# 'but' or '(and) yet'

Tags: conjunctions

In this sentence, which conjunction sounds more natural?

> This paper investigates one of these less known **but/and yet/yet** highly revealing statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are fine.  There's actually a lot of similarity between the conjunctions "but" and "yet" -- for example, these pairs of sentences each mean the same thing:

> She is petite **but** fit.
>   She is petite **yet** fit.
>
> The announcement was sensational **but** not surprising
>   The announcement was sensational **yet** not surprising

Because "yet" has another meaning, to imply future possibility (e.g. "He's not yet fifteen") there can be some nuance around its use, but this is really more about *writing style* than strict definition.

"And yet" is like "yet", but slightly more dramatic.  Imagine a salesman telling you something amazing about a product, "and yet, there's even another amazing thing that I'm going to tell you!"  It's fine to use it, but sparingly.